# Como faço para retornar um valor de uma Promise em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, promises, firefox-extensão

Bom estou enfrentando o seguinte problema, estou contribuindo em uma extensão do mozilla, mas a maioria do APIs do navegador usam promises para fazer as coisas, só que o problema é que não domino muito. Então gostaria mesmo é de saber como retornar o valor de uma promise para uma variável.

```js
a = function() {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(browser.storage.local.get().then(function(v) {
      ClockFormat=v.formClock;//aqui estou pegando um item do objeto da api
    }));
  });

  return promise;
};
a().then(function(result) {
    if(ClockFormat=="12"){
      console.log("12 horas");
    }else{
      console.log("24 horas");
    }
});
```

Obs: um detalhe que eu percebi é que do jeito que o código está a promise não consegue lidar funções que usam return, se não fosse isso teria terminado já.

Comment: Já tentou `browser.storage.local.get().then( v => {
      resolve(ClockFormat=v.formClock);
});` ?

Answer (score 1):

As Promises são assincronas, você já estudou linguagens assincronas antes ? Se não recomendo ler:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Os "retornos" das Promises sempre são acessados pela função .then() que funciona como um "try"ou .catch() que funciona como um "catch".
No .then() o retorno equivale ao valor passado para a funcão resolve() ao criar uma Promise ou o retorno do último .then(), já o .catch() que serve para tratamento de erros recebe apenas o parâmetro err do tipo Error que consiste em uma Exception com os dados do erro.

Já o ES2015 em diante é possível trabalhar com async/await, recomendo que leia: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas

Com isso é possível retornar o valor de uma Promise e atribuir a uma váriavel. Ex.:

```
const someFunction = async () => 
{
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(2));

    let result = await promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo Simples de **promise**.

```
var promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    let idade = 18

    if (idade >= 18) {
        resolve('Maior de idade.');
    } else {
        reject('Menor de idade.');
    }
});

promise.then( resultado => {
    console.log(resultado); //Maior de idade.
}, erro => {
    console.log(erro); //Menor de idade.
});
```